# Showing popover for the second time changes its position

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a function which creates popovers in my page, retrieving the content from an AJAX call. During the creation my function changes the popover position (it is page-wide, so I set to 0 the `left` attribute and move the arrow to point to my element). Everything works fine the *first* time, but if I move the mouse out and then in again the popover doesn't move from its default position (and neither does the arrow)

My code:

```
var last_opened_popover = null
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("*[data-poload]").mouseenter(function(){
        if (last_opened_popover != null){
            last_opened_popover.popover("destroy")
        }
        var element = jQuery(this)
        last_opened_popover = element
        var polId = element.data("poload")
        jQuery.ajax({
             url : my_url,
             type : "POST",
             data : {
                 //datas
         },
         success : function(result){
            var supporter_list = compose_supporter_list(result);
            var left = element.position().left + 75
            element.popover({
                content : supporter_list,
                html : true,
                placement : "bottom",
                template : '<div id="shown-popover" class="popover pgsc-popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
            })
            element.popover("show")
            var popover = jQuery("#shown-popover")
            popover.css("left", 0)
            popover.find(".arrow").css("left", left)
         }
      })
    }).mouseleave(function(){
       jQuery(this).popover("destroy")
    })
})
```

Comment: Is the missing comma on `url : my_url
             type : "POST",` just a typo?

Comment: You might be dealing with an issue related to all those missing semi-colons (try it with them IN the code)

Comment: What you THINK this does may not be the case: `var element = jQuery(this)
        last_opened_popover = element
        var polId = element.data("poload")`

Comment: Are you using any compression of the JS code?  What is `compose_supporter_list`

Comment: `polId` appears to be unused?

Comment: I removed some lines of code which are unrelated to the problem, like `compose_supporter_list`, which returns an unordered list, or where I use `polId`. Semicolons are no longere necessary in JavaScript, as long as you write one statement per line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that *all* the generated popover shared the same ID. Even if I destroied each one before creating another, the ID is somehow retained, so jQuery cannot access the new elements. The solution is to simply generate new IDs to make sure no popover share the same ID, I did it by simply using a counter:

```
var last_opened_popover = null
var popover_counter = 0
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("*[data-poload]").mouseenter(function(){
        if (last_opened_popover != null){
            last_opened_popover.popover("destroy")
        }
        var element = jQuery(this)
        last_opened_popover = element
        var polId = element.data("poload")
        jQuery.ajax({
             url : my_url,
             type : "POST",
             data : {
               //datas
             },
             success : function(result){
                var supporter_list = compose_supporter_list(result);
                var left = element.position().left + 75
                element.popover({
                    content : supporter_list,
                    html : true,
                    placement : "bottom",
                    template : '<div id="shown-popover-' + popover_counter  + '" class="popover pgsc-popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
               })
               element.popover("show")
               var popover = jQuery("#shown-popover-" + popover_counter)
               popover.css("left", 0)
               popover.find(".arrow").css("left", left)
               popover_counter++
            }
    })
})
```